# Cytoscape.js - custom nodes

Tags: javascript, svg, cytoscape.js

I understood that it's possible to create custom node styles as SVG images and then set it as the nodes' background image, but for some reason it doesn't work for me. Here's my code:

```
var cytoscapeStyle = [ // the stylesheet for the graph     
  {
    selector: 'node',
    style: {
      'background-color': 'white',
      'border-width': '6px',
      'label': 'data(id)',
      'background-image': 'node.svg', //doesn't work for some reason. Works when I use a png (e.g. node.png)
      'shape': 'roundrectangle',
      'width': '200px',
      'height': '90px'
    }
  },

  {
    "selector": "node:selected",
    "style": {
      "border-width": "6px",
      "border-color": "#AAD8FF",
      "border-opacity": "0.5",
      "background-color": "#77828C",
      "text-outline-color": "#77828C"
    }
  },

  {
    selector: 'edge',
    style: {
      'width': 3,
      'line-color': '#ccc',
      'target-arrow-color': '#ccc',
      'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
      'label': 'data(id)'
    }
  }
];
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SVG doesn't load, then the SVG image is invalid or doesn't specify dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

put the svg (Data uri) in your data{..} and set background-image to data(svg)

stylestuff

```
{
selector: 'node',
style: {
  'background-image': 'data(svg)'
}
```

nodestuff

```
cy.add([
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: { id: "somenode",
            svg: <image> //eg. "data:image/svg+xml;base64,<data>" 
                         //     or http://some.image.xyz

    }])
```